# Why are std:: symbols forcibly exported in shared libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

If your shared library uses C++ inside, then all the `std::` templates and types referenced by it will be exported as weak symbols. Even if you use `-fvisiblity=hidden` and `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`. The only way to hide those symbols is using a version script.

What's the purpose of these forced exports?

Is there any harm in hiding them with version scripts?

Answer (score 9):

So I found two (rejected) GCC-bugreports discussing this issue:

- [stl templates exported as weak symbols though visibility hidden is used](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36022)
- [--fvisibility=hidden doesn't hide stl implementation details.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50348)

The reasoning seems to be:

- Easier programming along library borders when using stl
- Easier testing of stl
- It's difficult overall to hide template implementation details consistently

Check out [this comment by Benjamin Kosnik](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36022#c4) especially. Cited for preservation purposes:

> This isn't a bug, but rather part of a deliberate linkage strategy.
>
> For C++, types that are to be used across shared libraries have to be
> visible. See:
>
> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options
>
> And in particular:
>
> Note that '-fvisibility' does affect C++ vague linkage entities. This
> means that, for instance, an exception class that will be thrown
> between DSOs must be explicitly marked with default visibility so that
> the 'type_info' nodes will be unified between the DSOs.
>
> Thus, the rationale for libstdc++ having namespace std have visibility
> "default." If you were to hack in support for allowing namespace std
> to have hidden visibility, and run the testsuite with
> -fvisibility=hidden (see attached patch) you would notice the breakdown in testresults, with mass failures. Thus, it is provided for
> information purposes only.
>
> In the libstdc++ source files, anonymous namespaces are used for
> specific entities that have both local/hidden linkage. This use of
> anonymous namespaces is considered superior to attribute hidden as it
> uses ISO C++ and is thus more portable than vendor extensions (pragmas
> or attributes).
>
> However, in libstdc++ header files, attribute hidden has been
> difficult to use. One might think that perhaps all the implementation
> details could be moved to say std::__detail, and then marked with
> attribute hidden. Then, many of these helper functions would be marked
> as hidden in your example below.
>
> There are some pitfalls with this approach:
>
> 1. all these implementation base types that are used by default
>    derived classes  would have to be default
> 2. same with implementation
>    details that use static locals
> 3. same with virtual functions, etc
>    etc.
> 4. thus you end up with a pretty limited set of hidden things
>
> In addition, this may exacerbate the dlopen + RTLD_LOCAL + weak symbol
> issue for C++.